# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidenav is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

All the time when I try to start a page, such an error occurs:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidenav is not a function
>
> at HTMLDocument. (index.html:59)
>
> at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>
> at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

Why does it arise? I did seem to have done everything right?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css" media="screen,projection" />

    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
        header,
        main,
        footer {
            padding-left: 300px;
        }

        @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

            header,
            main,
            footer {
                padding-left: 0;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </nav>

    <ul id="slide-out" class="sidenav">
        <li>
            <div class="user-view">
                <div class="background">
                    <img src="images/office.jpg">
                </div>
                <a href="#user"><img class="circle" src="images/yuna.jpg"></a>
                <a href="#name"><span class="white-text name">John Doe</span></a>
                <a href="#email"><span class="white-text email">jdandturk@gmail.com</span></a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>First Link With Icon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!">Second Link</a></li>
        <li>
            <div class="divider"></div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="subheader">Subheader</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect" href="#!">Third Link With Waves</a></li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.sidenav').sidenav();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think `.sidenav()` is part of Materialize; perhaps that's not loading properly (the browser Network tab will tell you that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try with materialise CDN .
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js`

Comment: I downloaded the exact same file and I had an error, and now once again I downloaded the same one and it disappeared what kind